# Problems printing out this star shape

Tags: c

While practicing I came across an assignment that required me to write a code which would print out the following shape:

https://postimg.cc/hJ7Hc72W

I tried a method where I had two for loops. I know the basic guidelines when it comes to printing star shapes but I simply can't complete this one. Whatever I do, I can just print out the left portion of the shape(the left pyramid) but the right one ends up being "warped".

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int length=2*n-1, width=2*n+1;
        for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<width; j++) {

         //The left side of the "||" separated condition prints the left pyramid,
// while the right side of the "||" should print out the right pyramid
               if( (i>=j && i<=length-1-j) || (i<=j && i>=length-1-j) ) 
             printf("*");



                else printf(" ");

            }
            printf("\n");
        }


    return 0;
}
```

However, what I end up with is always this: https://postimg.cc/628SY4G1

Any idea where I might be wrong? Thanks so much!

Comment: This is the kind of problem where using a debugger will give you a better idea of what's wrong.

Comment: The total length of each line is supposed to be `1 + n*2` assuming there is a single space between the two rows of length n in the middle. This means you have to write 2 for loops, 1 going up and 1 going back down. Then simply `print i stars`, `(1+n*2) - i*2 spaces` and again `print i stars` for each iteration/row.

Comment: The desired shape is plain text, no artwork. No need to use links to images of text while you can simply copy&paste the text directly into the question.

Comment: @Gerhardh So you automatically assume I didn't try to copy and paste the text, am I correct? I'm not quite sure what you wanted to achieve with a comment that does not contribute to the question in hand, but if you're still interested I'll have you know that I was not quite sure if the text formatting would alter the text when it comes to viewing the question via mobile phones or different computers, and pasting links was the only reliable way I found to convey the message I wanted to convey.

Comment: I don't assume you didn't try, but at SO people are not really keen to follow any links in questions. Questions that contain all the required information are appreciated. Some people simply ignore questions that require to follow links. You could edit your question to include the test (formatted as code) to attract more readers.

Comment: @Gerhardh See, that is a much nicer and more comprehensible(at least to a newbie on the internet and programming) way of conveying what you wanted to say in your original comment. I'm glad you see that there actually is a way, without making assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping over everywhere and filtering to determine which character to print (as you have noticed, this is surprisingly tricky to get right), break the figure down into sections.

Start with printing a single line, `width` wide and with `stars` stars.

This can be done with three loops:

```
void print_line(int width, int stars)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < stars; i++)
       printf("*");
    for (int i = 0; i < width-2*stars; i++)
       printf(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < stars; i++)
       printf("*");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Then write a loop for the top `n-1` lines and a loop for the bottom `n-1` lines, with one full-width line inbetween:

```
int width = 2*n+1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n-1; i++)
    print_line(width, i);
print_line(width, n);
for (int i = n-1; i >= 1; i--)
    print_line(width, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i,j,k;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int length=2*n-1;
    int reqd_no_of_stars;
    for(i=0; i<=length; i++)
    {
        if(length+1-i<i)
        {
            reqd_no_of_stars=length+1-i;
        }
        else
        {
            reqd_no_of_stars=i;
        }
        for(k=0; k<reqd_no_of_stars; k++)
            printf("*");//print left set of stars equal to the number of reqd_no_of_stars
        for(k=0; k<(2*n+1)-2*reqd_no_of_stars; k++)
            printf(" ");//print required spaces=total_width-required_width_for_stars=((2*n+1)-2*reqd_no_of_stars) in between stars of both sides
        for(k=0; k<reqd_no_of_stars; k++)
            printf("*");//print right set of stars equal to the number of reqd_no_of_stars
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you structure your code, you'll have very little problem in painting the ties:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char AST[] = "**********";
static const char BLK[] = "          ";

void paint_line(const char *s, int n)
{
    int l = strlen(s);
    while (n >= l) {
        fputs(s, stdout);
        n -= l;
    }
    /* n < l */
    if (n > 0)
    printf("%.*s", n, s);
}

void paint_tie(int n)
{
    int row;
    for(row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
        paint_line(AST, row);
        paint_line(BLK, 2*(n-row) + 1);
        paint_line(AST, row);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (row = n-1; row > 0; row--) {
        paint_line(AST, row);
        paint_line(BLK, 2*(n-row) + 1);
        paint_line(AST, row);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        int n = atoi(argv[i]);
        paint_tie(n);
    }
}
```

The routine `main()` just extracts the sizes of the ties from the command line.  I've not included code to check if `atoi(3)` returns the proper value, but for sure you can complete the exercise.

The routine `paint_tie()` prints one tie, it just prints the lines with the number of characters that are requested, growing up to `n`, then waning to zero again.

Finally, the routine `paint_line` just paints a sequence of chars, selected from a string passed as a parameter.  It prints as many complete strings (just trying to be efficient) using the function `fputs(3)` until there's no more place for a full string, it then uses (only once, as that's expensive) the `%.*s` format, which allows me to get the first part of the string, up to the trailing characters that are not multiple of the string length.  You can download the example [here](https://github.com/mojadita/so/tree/master/57458702).

BTW, why do you ask this?  Is it a homework exercise, or you are just practicing (as you say in your question) Any case, you are doing bad just asking here, as you are not exercising yourself.  Why do you auto ask to do an exercise, and then come here to look for the answer? Cannot understand.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it has been most valuable.

As for your question, you actually answered the first part yourself. If you look hard enough you might be able to notice it. And generally your assumption that I have not been exercising myself is not only unnecessary but also a very bold one. I sincerely hope you understand that you can not possibly know the time I spent doing this exercise to no avail. It is not a matter of hours but better yet of several days.